# Rails, many instances for one model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, upload

How can I create many instances of one model in one form?
In my case user must be able to upload many files with descriptions in one time.

Answer (score 0):

If there is an association between users and files in your models, you can use nested attributes to build your form with attributes from each model. Check out http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes to get started

Your form would look something like this:

```
<%= form_for @user do |user_form| %>
  First name: <%= user_form.text_field :first_name %>
  Last name : <%= user_form.text_field :last_name %>

  <%= fields_for @user.files do |file_fields| %>
    <%= file_fields.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```